# display nothing after sort array in php

Tags: php

I want to sort in ascending order field *available_price* in an array, how can I sort. Following are code

```
Array
(
    [available_price] => 770
    [category] => Fashion design & theory
    [mrp] => 770
    [source] => RediffBooks
    [title] => Shoes
    [url] => http://books.rediff.com/book/five-point-someone/9781851775378
)
Array
(
    [available_price] => 797
    [mrp] => 938
    [source] => URead-IN
    [title] => Shoes
    [url] => http://www.uread.com/search-books/9781851775378
)
```

... so on...

Comment: php offers convenient sorting functions. Did you take a look at those?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`usort()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php) to sort your array based on `available_price`:

```
$array = array(
   array(
     available_price => 770,
     category => "Fashion design & theory",
     mrp => 770,
     source => "RediffBooks",
     title => "Shoes",
     url => "http://books.rediff.com/book/five-point-someone/9781851775378"
   ),
   array(
     available_price => 797,
     mrp => 938,
     source => "URead-IN",
     title => "Shoes",
     url => "http://www.uread.com/search-books/9781851775378"
   ),
);

// sort the items in the array in ascending order based on available_price
usort($array, function($a, $b) {
   return $a['available_price'] > $b['available_price'];
});
```

Comment: `return $a['available_price'] < $b['available_price'];` should be `return $a['available_price'] - $b['available_price'];`

Answer (score -2):

You should put all your arrays into one array and then loop then with bubble sort method OR use sort function with your defined compare function.

Comment: OP should in fact be using the "BakeSale" method of Array organisation, following the W3C official recommendations that array order is defined by flour and sugar concentrate in equal volumes.

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply, but still sorting not working. Following are my code.


foreach($data2 as $data3){


print_r($data3['available_price']);

 usort($array, function($a, $b) {
   return $a['available_price'] > $b['available_price'];
});

}


but nothing result is displaying. where i am wrong ?